DRF Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.) from React axios POST request
As we know, we don't have access to Django CSRFToken in React by default, So we have to get it somehow.
The solution was make a URL for receive CSRFToken in Response-Headers and set csrftoken cookie in browser. So I did it =>
Views.py
@method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie, name='dispatch')
class GetCSRFToken(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return Response("CSRF cookie set.")

CSRFToken.jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function CSRFToken(){

    useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const url = 'http://localhost:8000/csrf_cookie'
                const response = await axios.get(url,{
                    withCredentials: true,
                }).then(()=>{
                    console.log("CSRF Cookie set.")
                })
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
        </>
    )
    
} 

Result =>

After that we can access to csrftoken and We can send it through X-CSRFToken Request-Headers.
But the problem is when I send the request, Django side won't accept that csrftoken and will reject that request.
settings.py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'App.apps.AppConfig'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:5173']

Views.py
@method_decorator(csrf_protect, name='dispatch')
class MarketDataView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        ...

FetchMarketData.js
export const fetchMarketData = createAsyncThunk(
  'market/fetchData',
  async ({requestData, csrftoken}, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/market'
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          exchange: 'binance'
        }),
      });
      return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);

Request Headers and Django Response =>


How can I solve this problem guys?
